# Matching parent, though value in parent OR child solr

Tags: solr, lucene

I have been experimenting with solr for a couple of weeks but i've been stuck on a query i would like to execute for a couple of days now.

I have a nested data structure where I'm using a fq like this:

```
{!parent which="parentDoc:true"}parentDoc:false AND <searched term>
```

This matches my child documents and returns the parent to those children. I am very pleased with that. BUT the problem i have is if there is a match directly inside the parent and nothing in the children. I will not get a response.

I would make it so that in some way there is a OR condition of some sort making it so, any document can match the searched term AND parentDoc:false OR the above filter query.

Is this even possible to execute within one query in solr, or do i have to make  two? I have not found any information about this issue, making me to believe im just missing something trivial.

Answer (score 0):

`<searched term>` from your FQ refer to parents not to children, since you have only parents in the results after join.
Also your `<searched term>` is a totally separate condition than your join command.

Put `q=*:*` and if you want to filter by children conditions you can use in fq:

```
+{!parent which=parentDoc:true v='parentDoc:false AND (<children_conditions>)'} AND <parents_conditions>
```

In case you want to expand children then add RAW query:

```
expand.field=_root_&expand=true&expand.fq=*:*
```

or more specific:

```
expand.field=_root_&expand=true&expand.fq=(parentDoc:false AND (<children_conditions>))
```